# How to override CloudWatch Logs Method settings at resource level?

Tags: serverless, serverless-framework

Does serverless support [Method Overrides](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/stages.html#how-to-method-override) feature?

**My use case:**
Using below configuration, we get logs enabled including access logs, full execution logs. However these are applied to all resources of the API. I would like to override these settings at a resource level. AWS Web Console has option to configure log level per resource in deployed stage. How could I get this override per given resource a.k.a lambda function.

My use case involves not logging request/response for a specific resource but I need these logs for other resources on the same API.

```
logs: {
      restApi: true,
    },
```